# need to replace xml attribute value using shell script

Tags: shell-script, sed, xml

sample `input.xml` file

```xml
<user dn="CN=company,DN=Department">
<role name="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</user>
```

output should be

```xml
<user dn="String_1,String_2">
<role name="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</user>
```

Please advice me on the above problem statement.
Note: dn shouldn't be hard coded as the value could be blank as well.eg dn=""

Comment: It will be great if people who downvoted this question, explain why the bad reviews.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `sed` to manipulate XML, use an XML-aware tool like `xmlstarlet` instead:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/user/@dn' -v 'String1, String2' input.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

With the command-line XML parser/editor [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
$ company="The Company"
$ department="The Department"

$ dn="CN=$company,DN=$department"

$ xml ed -t -u '/user/@dn' -v "$dn" input.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user dn="CN=The Company,DN=The Department">
  <role name="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</user>
```

This command will look up the `dn` attribute of the root node `user` and edit its value to be whatever `$dn` expands to.

For ease of parsing the `dn` attribute later, it may be worth using a more prominent delimiter between the company name and the following `DN` in the attribute value. For example a `;` rather than a `,`. Or add them as separate attributes to the `user` node.

Answer (score 1):

If the `<user...>` line is always on its own then this is a simple expression in sed

```
sed "s/^<user .*/<user dn=\"$string1,$string2\">/" input.xml
```

Now this was written so that `$string1` and `$string2` are variables.

So, for example:

```
$ string1="hello"
$ string2="there"
$ sed "s/^<user .*/<user dn=\"$string1,$string2\">/" input.xml
<user dn="hello,there">
<role name="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
</user>
```

You can use `sed -i` for an "in place" replacement, which will rewrite `input.xml`.

Answer (score -1):

`sed` is your friend

```
 sed '/^<user dn=/s/CN=[^,]*,DN=[^"]*\"/String_1,String2/' filename
```

should do it. If you wish `String_1` & `String_2` to be chosen real-time, you can use variables to achieve this. I would write a script

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p"Enter string1" str1
read -p"Enter string2" str2
sed -i "/^<user dn=/s/CN=[^,]*,DN=[^\"]*\"/$str1,$str2/" /path/to/input.xml
```

The `-i` option modifies the file straightaway.

---

**Note**

The double quotes are used in the sed script because they would allow bash variable expansion. Though, for the same reason we have escaped the double quotes that come in the pattern itself.

---

Comment: sed is not your friend when it comes to processing XML.  or HTML.  or json.

Comment: @cas : No doubt there are better/specialized tools like [\[ xmllint \]](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) . But for this simple task, `sed` is indeed a good try.

Comment: no, using sed or any other line-oriented regexp tool with xml is too fragile - even the smallest changes in input is likely to break the script.  If you want to use sed, at least pre-process it with `xml2` to convert to a line-oriented format, and then `2xml` to convert it back to xml.  e.g. `xml2 <file.xml | sed ... | 2xml > file.new.xml`